# Angular.js ternery statement on HTML tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```html
 <h4 class="changecolor">{{driver.name}}&nbsp;</h4>
<h4 class="changecolor" ng-show="!driver.name">{{driver.officeEmail}}&nbsp;</h4>
```

If the `driver.name` is not available then show the `driver.officeEmail`

Is there a way to implement this in one line, using  ternary statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only want to use one binding, try:

```
<h4 class="changecolor">{{driver.name || driver.officeEmail}}</h4>
```

This is called [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). If `driver.name` is undefined, then `driver.officeEmail` will be shown instead.

Comment: My friend, Thanks a lot.This solution helped me.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @quantumwannabe works and is a better solution for this particular use case, but the OP asked about ternary which is also possible since version 1.2.x.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller('appCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.driver = {email : "test"};
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <h4 class="changecolor">{{driver.name ? driver.name : driver.email}}</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<h4 class="changecolor">{{(driver.name) ? driver.name : driver.officeEmail}}&nbsp;</h4>
```

This worked for me.

Comment: You don't need the () around driver.name it will work without it like in my example below